# Choosing framework for writing into cassandra database using Java

Tags: database, nosql, cassandra, key-value, hector

Hi am new to database programming, am in a project where i need to write data to noSql database currently we choosed Cassandra as our DB.

But its not final i need to come up with a framework or library service where any of application request data from DB, this library should serve it.
I choosed to use the "Hector" framework with that i can able to write to cassandra DB, but requirement is if tommorow we change database my library has to work with new database where we just store data as key-value pair.

Please help me to get solution to this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you decided to go with Hector, it is recommended to use [DataStax Java Driver](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver).

It is built from the very beginning to take advantage of Cassandra's new CQL native protocol. I used Hector in the past and it is too much annoying to use and code in.

[DataStax Java Driver: A new face for Cassandra](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/new-datastax-drivers-a-new-face-for-cassandra)

Comment: Thanks Chiron for your reply. I have used the Hector for working with Cassandra, it looks ok.. Interface is not as good as Hbase.